# UnicodeDecodeError with character 0x81 parsed with csv.reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-unicode

I've just ran code that used to work in Python 2.7 on 3.7 (via miniconda). It's basically a library produced by the land registry that parses CSV addressing data.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AddressBasePremium_RecordSplitter37.py", line 730, in <module>
    main()
  File "AddressBasePremium_RecordSplitter37.py", line 726, in main
    createCSV()
  File "AddressBasePremium_RecordSplitter37.py", line 507, in createCSV
    for row in csvreader:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3130:
                        character maps to <undefined>
```

Opening the CSV file in VSCode it tells me the file is UTF-8 (or so it thinks), so I'm a bit stumped. The character at fault is as shown below. How can I fix this? I presumed being UTF-8 it would be fine, but given it's an extra character it must be UTF-16 or some other unicode character set? which I find a bit odd as I'd presume the data to be in UTF-8 coming from UK Land Registry.

The code is essentially this:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(
        f,
        delimiter=",",
        doublequote=False,
        lineterminator="\n",
        quotechar='"',
        quoting=0,
        skipinitialspace=True,
    )
    try:
        for row in csvreader:
            abtype = row[0]
            if "10" in abtype:
                write10.writerow(row)
                counter10 += 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the encoding to the open function:

For an utf-8 file, you would do this:

```
with open(filepath, "r",encoding="utf-8")
```

Explanation: your file is read in cp1252 encoding, but the character 0x81 does not exists in cp1252 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My Python is a bit rusty and I presumed that first 2to3 would make a comment on issues like this for some reason and I had it in my head that Python 3 defaulted to unicode whereas Python 2. didn't.